# Conditionally sum values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT R.IDrota, (SELECT count(*) FROM VendaVoo where ocupacao = 1 and IDvoo= V.IDvoo and V.IDrota = R.IDrota) as VENDAS  FROM voo V
JOIN VendaVoo VV ON VV.IDvoo = V.IDvoo
JOIN rota R ON V.IDrota = R.IDrota
GROUP BY R.IDrota, V.IDvoo, V.IDrota
order by IDrota
```

This gives me this table:

[image: table]

This table has some "IDrota" repeated. My goal is too sum that values and have unique "IDrota".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT R.IDrota,
       SUM(CASE WHEN vv.ocupacao = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Vendas
FROM voo V JOIN
     VendaVoo VV
     ON VV.IDvoo = V.IDvoo JOIN
     rota R
     ON V.IDrota = R.IDrota
GROUP BY R.IDrota
ORDER BY R.IDrota;
```

Comment: Think you might have been beaten to it :)

Comment: @DaleK, my average typing speed is 124 wpm

Comment: But sadly i got negative vote, higher reputation got this advantage.

Comment: I just cannot see why this was downvoted (even if it wasn't first)...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sum()` and `case` to get the result you want. There is no need for a `subquery`. `grouping` should only be by `IDrota`

```
SELECT R.IDrota, 
    sum(case when VV.ocupacao = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as VENDAS  
FROM voo V
JOIN VendaVoo VV ON VV.IDvoo = V.IDvoo
JOIN rota R ON V.IDrota = R.IDrota
GROUP BY R.IDrota
order by R.IDrota
```